# Cannot upload large files despite increasing post_max_size and upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, apache, post, upload, ubuntu-16.04

We need to be able to upload files up to 50 MB through our PHP website (stored in the MySQL DB as `LONGBLOB`s - bad, I know). I increased the `post_max_size` to `200M` and `upload_max_filesize` to `50M` however even much smaller files cannot get posted (500 KB is okay but 2 MB or so does not get uploaded).

I suspect this could be a memory issue. I set `memory_limit` to `256M` (compared to the original `128M` which only allowed very small files to be posted) but it's still not enough. I could set it to `-1` but I would rather set it to a certain value which would be enough to post 50 MB files (max four of these in a single post).

Any idea how to calculate the value I need to set it to? Or maybe the issue lies somewhere else?

Thanks.

Comment: what phpinfo tells about the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize?

Comment: it shows the updated values.

Comment: Did you reload your configuration files after updating ?

Comment: Do you mean reloading apache service? I did

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute query which tells what is the max size of the statement send to mysql from your client:

```
 'SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = <bytes>'
```

so for 50MB you would have 50*1024*1024

And for the pdo (in case you are using pdo):

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, <bytes>);
```

Comment: `(stored in the DB as LONGBLOBs - bad, I know)` and I assumed is sql database

Comment: I do have MySQL and the uploaded files are inserted into the DB as `LONGBLOB`s but this setting is already set to 52428800.

Comment: and I suppose you checked that value with a simple select to the DB ?

Comment: you are using pdo I guess?

Comment: I am (using Propel ORM which uses PDO). I tried that but i'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE'`

Comment: which php version you are running?

Comment: 7.0.11. v7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 to be exact

Comment: if you are using mysqlnd - MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE is not supported (also it is not supported in some PDO versions). Try google it , but this is the reason you are not able to upload bigger files. PDO limits the query size.

Comment: are you sure it's a PDO issue? Just tried uploading a 2 MB file on the same website (same code, running on different MySQL databases. I set  the relevant variables in `php.ini` to the same values) on my local WAMP server and also a different server (running PHP5 and an older MySQL version) and it worked fine. I also tested uploading a file just under 1 MB and one just over 1 MB and the former one was posted, the other wasn't.

Comment: You can easily test it on the failing server with query which is bigger in size. For example you can create test table with longtext field and make query using php + pdo which inserts big entry in this table. This test will not be limited by php.ini variables you already changed, so it will tell you for sure what the problem is.